# Column with ranking based on other columns but like tie breaker

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rank

I've got a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "DScore": [2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "EScore": [6, 7, 9, 9, 10],
    "Total Score": [17, 15, 15, 23, 25]
})
```

I want to write the code that will create a ranking column containing the classification of rows in the table based on the 'Total Score' column. If these values ​​are equal - you should pay attention to the values ​​​​of EScore points, if they are equal, then it will be based on the values ​​​​from the DScore column, and if these are also equal - we will assign them the same value. Expected result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "DScore": [2, 2, 4, 4, 5],
    "EScore": [6, 7, 9, 9, 10],
    "Total Score": [17, 15, 23, 23, 25],
    "Rank": [3,4,2,2,1]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can multiply the `EScore` by 0.01 and the `DScore` by 0.001 to weight them more lightly. Then, you can add these values to `Total Score` and calculate the rank.

rank with `method=dense` & `ascending=False`

```
df['Rank'] = df['Total Score'].add(df['EScore'].mul(0.01)).add(df['DScore'].mul(0.0001)).rank(ascending=False, method='dense').astype('int')
```

df

```
   DScore  EScore  Total Score  Rank
0       2       6           17     3
1       2       7           15     4
2       4       9           23     2
3       4       9           23     2
4       5      10           25     1
```

The example you provided is sufficient with `0.01` and `0.0001`, but these numbers should be adjusted to fit the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Define the order of columns, then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
# desired order of tie-breakers
cols = ['Total Score', 'EScore', 'DScore']

df['Rank'] = (df.sort_values(by=cols, ascending=False)
                .groupby(cols, sort=False).ngroup().add(1)
             )
```

Output:

```
   DScore  EScore  Total Score  Rank
0       2       6           17     3
1       2       7           15     4
2       4       9           23     2
3       4       9           23     2
4       5      10           25     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the pandas `rank` function

```py
df['Rank']= df['Total Score'].rank(ascending=False).astype(int)
```

```
   DScore  EScore  Total Score  Rank
0       2       6           17     4
1       2       7           15     5
2       4       9           23     2
3       4       9           23     2
4       5      10           25     1
```

Note you can modify the ranking method (5 values) :

```
method{‘average’, ‘min’, ‘max’, ‘first’, ‘dense’}, default ‘average’
```

And with parameter set to `dense` it "compresses the counting" :

```py
df['Rank']= df['Total Score'].rank(ascending=False, method='dense').astype(int)
```

```
   DScore  EScore  Total Score  Rank
0       2       6           17     3
1       2       7           15     4
2       4       9           23     2
3       4       9           23     2
4       5      10           25     1
```